# Waveshare RS485 CAN hat over raspberry pi 3A+

Tags: spi, config.txt, can-bus

So I have been at least trying to connect to the hat from the Pi, the following is my configuration:
[image]

I follow the manual set in this link: https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/2/29/RS485-CAN-HAT-user-manuakl-en.pdf

However I get the following output when checking if the connection is successful:
[image]

This is my config.txt file:
[image]

I use the oscillator with that number since the version of the hat I have uses that oscillation value. I use dtoverlay=spi0-hw-cs instead of the usual dtoverlay=spi0-bcm2835-overlay because my overlays folder is as shown:

[image]

I have checked the wiring multiple times, tried to reduce the spimaxfrequency, checked the interrupt pin in the config.txt file to be sure its connecting to the correct pin of the Pi, but all to no avail.

Can anyone please help? It's for an important uni project...

Comment: Hi @aldo, Welcome and nice to meet you.  Ah, let me see. First thing first, please let me know how do you do with the following: (1) $ uname -a, (2) $ ls /dev/spi*. / to continue, ...

Comment: Second thing. Let us see if our docs are in sync: (1) RS485 CAN HAT Overview and Features - WaveShare
https://www.waveshare.com/rs485-can-hat.htm

(2) RS485 CAN HAT Wiki - WaveShare 
https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/RS485_CAN_HAT

(3) RS485 CAN HAT User Manual - WaveShare
https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/2/29/RS485-CAN-HAT-user-manuakl-en.pdf. / to continue, ...

Comment: Third. If possible, beg/steal/borrow the following or similar, and confirm our docs in sync: 
(4) USB TO RS232/RS485/TTL Industrial Isolated Converter Overview and Features - WaveShare
https://www.waveshare.com/usb-to-rs232-485-ttl.htm

(5) USB TO RS232/485/TTL Wiki - WaveShare
https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/USB_TO_RS232/485/TTL

(6)USB TO RS232/485/TTL User Manual - WaveShare
https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/e/e4/USB_TO_RS232_485_TTL_-user-manual-en.pdf. /to continue, ...

Comment: I will be brainstorming quick and dirty troubleshooting ideas. This forum is only for short Q&A. It would be nice if you can let me know your public GitHub/GitLab/ProjectBlog with more details such as: (version of HAT, 10HMz or 12MHz), You DSC (Digital Storage ／。。Ａｈ　ｓｏｒｒｙ　Ｉ　ｈａｖｅ　ａｎ　Ｅｎｇ　ｔｏ　Ｃｈｉ　ｃｌａｓｈ，　ｎｅｅｄ　ｔｏ　ｒｅｓｅｔ．　Ｎｅｖｅｒ　ｍｉｎｄ　ｉｆ　ｙｏｕ　ｓｅｅ　ｆｕｎｎｙ　ｃｈａｒａｃｔｅｒｓ．　Ｐｅｒｈａｐｓ　ｃｏｍｅ　ｂａｃｋ　ｔｈｉｓ　ａｆｔｅｒｎｏｏｎ

Comment: I am using Chinese Win10 to talk and might show funny characters here and there, now and then.  In case you read weird chars. Let me know and I can extract docs from my Chinese Wiki/blog/penzu test log/diary for your more pleasant reading. 拜拜.

Comment: I must confess that I have very little practical experience with CAN/485, though I know pretty well UART/SPI/I2C. So be warned that I might mislead you by amateurishly stupid suggestions. Now let me brainstorm a test plan: (1) just try SPI, forget the UART part. (2) The software/drivers the tutorial recommend is "universal" for all versions of Rpi. If you are using Rpi3A+ buster/stretch/jessie/wheezy? You might not need to following the tutorial's install guides, expecially when using pip/pip3 which might confuse the raspbain.

Comment: (3) I would suggest to focus on the python version of setup and debug, because (a) C/C++ language is hard to debug/develop, (b) WiringPi is depreciated, no long supported. Ah lunch time. See you late evening or tomorrow.  Cheers.

Comment: Your connection failure error message above says "Error 19: probe failed, SPI0.0 cannot initialize MCP2515". So I would suggest to first troubleshoot MCP2515 in two steps: (1) make sure SPI 0.0 wiring/driver are OK by using python SPI loopback test, (2) Use python to write and read MCPO2515 config register, to make sure the HAT should be OK to do similar.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Comment: And if you are not using GitHub or blog, perhaps you can show us a preliminary, quick and dirty, skeleton, draft of your project report, to convenience us that your uni project is really "important" :).  Project report example: Home Security System Using Rpi3, DH11, HC-SR501, A Design Project Report - J Wang, H Ping, M Fang, Cornell MSEE 2019
https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/eceprojectsland/STUDENTPROJ/2018to2019/jw2527_hp394_mf734/project_142_report.pdf. Cheers.